# How to send non english character in json from php?

Tags: php, json, slim

I have a non-english word e.g 'परीक्षण' in database.I fetch the data from slim framework (Php) and the code is :

```
        while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
         $data[]=$row;
        }
         return $response->withStatus(200)
        ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        ->write(json_encode($data));
```

The response is for e.g;

```
          [{"s.n":"1","english_word":"test","nepali_word":"???????"}]
```

Could someone please tell me how can I send the non-english word in Json from php?

Comment: This is not a question of json or php, but of your setup. You need to take care that _all_ components involved in your tool chain use the same encoding, preferably UTF-8. Start reading here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: Use language translation libraries

Comment: @arkascha thank you very much

Comment: @PrashantGPatil thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you may want to use the `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` constant

```
$arr = ['s.n' => 1, 'english_word' => 'test', 'nepali_word' => 'परीक्षण'];

echo json_encode($arr, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

// Output : {"s.n":1,"english_word":"test","nepali_word":"परीक्षण"}
```

live demo : https://3v4l.org/DVejS

---

in your issue context , when using headers like `Content-Type: application/json` you will need to set the charset too as follows:

```
->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8;')
```

Comment: it was a typo , I've fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
        $data[]=$row;
}
return $response->withStatus(200)
    ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    ->write(json_encode(mb_convert_encoding($data, "HTML-ENTITIES", "UTF-8")));
```

Comment: yes you can also tried this.  $data = "यह कार है";
        echo  json_encode(mb_convert_encoding($data, "HTML-ENTITIES", "UTF-8"));

Comment: first error you will get from your code is that mb_convert_encode only accepts a string while you are sending an array to it. `$data` is an array :)

Answer (score -1):

there are couple of possibilities in these situations:

**possibility -1:** your database column encoding might be not supporting the characters (check the encoding of the column and use utf8mb4 for mysql). in that case when you insert not supported character like "ع" , the database will convert it to real actual question mark "?" . **you lost the characters forever** and you will still see question marks ??? whatever you do

**possibility -2:** your database is using the correct encoding and you have your characters stored in the database correctly, but you still seeing question marks "?????" . in that case the program that showing the characters (text editor,web browser,...etc ) is using a wrong encoding.

what to do now ?

1- check your database column encoding to see if it is supports utf-8.()

2- check the encoding of the whatever program you are using the characters throw (browser, text editor,Mysql workbench,..etc )